# Can't select OS with remote in Burg

Tags: burg, remote

I use BURG where i can select one of 3 OS (Openelec - Windows - Ubuntu). But selecting don't work with my remote control. I can use my remote for starting the system, but not for choosing the OS. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

BURG/grub isn't linux, and so linux solutions won't work for this. 
The only practical way I see this working is if you can a remote control that pretends to be a usb keyboard.

Non-practical ways-

1. BIOS supports remote (open source BIOS?)
2. Using linux as a bootloader